# click on unknown element .net

Tags: html, vb.net, dom, getelementsbyclassname

i will explain everything

so it will be at least useful. i searched many times without any good point i failed, hope some help,

please don't vote "unclear question".

---

i trying to click on specific

> Dianna

Example:

```
<div class="Center_Home"><ul class="board"><li Address-Of-Center="Dianna" class="tile"></li></ul></div>
```

Here is my code that grabs div and all Required Classes elements.

```
   Dim elementList As HtmlElementCollection
    Dim curElement As HtmlElement
    elementList = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")

    For Each curElement In elementList

        If curElement.GetAttribute("classname").Equals("ul") Then

            curElement.InvokeMember("click")

        End If

        If curElement.GetAttribute("classname").Contains("Dianna") Then

            curElement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If

    Next
```

Addition info : i dont know if it important

### > layout board : ul.board

### > board inside : li.tile

> Also i found this similar page it may help too :
>   https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework/write-tests-in-code/intermediate-topics-wtc/element-identification-wtc/finding-page-elements

Big Thanks ....I try VB.NET for a while 
and Glade i Found This Great Forum. i asked Several question's And all Answered.

Comment: `className` refers _**only**_ to the `class="..."` attribute. [`TagName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.tagname) is the element type. Either get the first child of the `ul` element when found, _**or**_ simply change your loop to iterate all the elements and check if `GetAttribute("Address-Of-Center")` equals `"Dianna"`.

Comment: @VisualVincent , Not work yet, i can upload another Html Body Example if that can help me more ?!

Comment: Please update the question with your new/modified VB.NET code so I can examine it.

Comment: @VisualVincent Big thx i got what you meant, i changed my loop, and it work now fine

but you the reason of that it work, (only i changed "div" To "li" , and it work now,

Comment: @VisualVincent i want make your Mark As answered your Post .

Comment: Posted below. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`className` refers only to the `class="..."` attribute, not all attributes on the element. You need to iterate the `li` elements instead and specifically check the `Address-Of-Center` attribute.

```
'curElement is declared by the loop, no need to make a variable of it.

Dim elementList As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("li")

For Each curElement As HtmlElement In elementList
    If curElement.GetAttribute("Address-Of-Center").Equals("Dianna") Then
        curElement.InvokeMember("click")
        Exit For 'You must stop looping when you've found the element.
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Big Thanks You Are The Best.

That's Why We love stackoverflow.

For them Effort To improve Skills.